# Getting specific part from string

Tags: python, string, split, sessionid

```py
import re
import requests

from datetime import datetime

link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'

username = 'sem______________________'
password = 'Kolther2201!'

def sessionID():
    time = int(datetime.now().timestamp())

    payload = {
    'username': f'{username}',
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{time}:{password}',
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get(link)
        csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",r.text)[0]
        r = s.post(login_url,data=payload,headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "Referer": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/",
            "x-csrftoken":csrf
        })

        cookies = str(s.cookies)
        # print(cookies.split('sessionid', 1))
        print(cookies)

sessionID()
```

Hey I'm trying to just print out the `sessionid` from this output:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie csrftoken=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie ds_user_id=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie ig_did=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie mid=XXX for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie rur="XXX" for .instagram.com/>, <Cookie sessionid=XXX for .instagram.com/>]>
```

What is the easiest way to go about this? I'm uncertain if the length of the sessionid will always be the same.

Comment: Did you try `s.cookies['sessionid']`?